# After Add custom option in store level shows html in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0.2

[image]

In Store level custom option display as a attach my screenshot. Why.? In All Storeview Custom Option Working Fine. But In Multistore When I choose perticular store custom option display as screen shot.